# Embedding Unmanaged Visualforce Page/Component into a Managed one

Tags: visualforce, package, managed-package

I have a situation in which I'm required to 'embed' visualforce into another visualforce page dependent upon a custom setting. There will be different implementations of this visualforce (which will contain JS) dependent upon the custom setting, which interact with different external systems. The problem I have is that the page itself will be managed, but the visualforce I wish to embed will be unmanaged. Is there a feasible way to do this?

I've tried:

- A managed 'ComponentBuilderBase' class which is subclassed in unmanaged code. It's instantiated dynamically using the custom setting and the Type class. It's then used to dynamically instantiate an Apex Component, filling in an apex:dynamicComponent element. However, unmanaged code is unable to cast a type to a managed interface (Internal Salesforce Error is returned).
- Using apex:composition to embed a template, and dynamically retrieving the template. It seems that the managed visualforce can't find the unmanaged visualforce, as the page just returns as 'Does not exist'.

Comment: have you tried the local/c namespace for referring to your unmanaged page? e.g. `c__YourUnmanagedPage` instead of `YourUnmanagedPage`

Comment: Since you're getting a gack, it seems like that *should* work, but doesn't because of a glitch on the platform. You might try opening a case with salesforce.com directly, and see if they can look in to it for you.

Comment: @PhilHawthorn That seems to have worked perfectly for the second solution - thanks!

Comment: @sfdcfox True, I thought it was a bit odd that it didn't. I can't see why it would allow me to instantiate something that extends this class, but not cast an object into it. I may do this also.